# How to run both FrontEnd and Backend on same server?

Tags: angular, apache, flask, gunicorn, angular-fullstack

I am developing a web application and I would like to run both the frontend (an Angular application) and the backend (a flask application) on the same machine.

Doing some research I decided to use Apache HTTP as a web server for giving access to user to the frontend. Then I will use Gunicorn and Flask for my backend.

I would like to have the following folder structure:

```
MyProject
   |
    - /frontend
   |
    - /backend
```

I already developed some simple APIs and I was able to connect Apache, Guniciorn, and Flask. Now my backend's endpoints are reachable from the internet. For example at http://10.20.20.40/api/helloworld.

But what I would really like to do would be to make the front end reachable at some URL like http://10.20.20.40 and my backend only reachable from the frontend. Is this possible? Even both reachable would be ok.

How can I do that in a clean and simple way?

I really need some help with the Apache configuration. I think I should modify the .conf file.

Answer (score -1):

Need to build your angular code so it is just html and js files that can be hosted by apache.  Then anything starting with API apache will forward on to a different port.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea... but how to do it? Can you provide the .congig for apache and gunicorn?